# How to access the controls of a single item of a list view

Tags: android

How do i access the controls of an list view on item Click listener in a list view? As i have set the customize layout for a single list view item.

Comment: just type your question in Google you will get solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Attaching an item click listener

In the actvity where your listview is created try something similar to these

```
private void setupListView() {

    //find by view id
    customListView = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_listview);

    //set custom adapter
    customListView.setAdapter(
    new CustomListAdapter(this, R.id.lv_listview, variableList));

    //attach listener
    customListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            /* whatever happens when you click the list item goes here */

        }
    });
}
```